How to tell latex where to find the .cls file?
So I have this folder structure:
root
|- main.tex
|- myfolder
   |- abc.cls

When I want to compile main.tex:
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{abc}
\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}

it says that it can't find abc.cls. How do I fix this?
I'm using Latex Workshop within VS Code.
Thanks!

either put abc.cls in the same place as main.tex or arrange that TEXINPUTS=.//: before calling pdflatex so it looks in subdirectories of the current directory

@DavidCarlisle thanks! I can't change the directory because it is inside a repo which i cannot change. How do I that with TEXINPUTS?

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te

See also: Is there any way to set environment variables in Visual Studio Code?

You can use latexmk and then use the solution(s) from Overleaf can't find the document class when it's in a folder (note: Overleaf uses latexmk).

If the code is inside a repository then nobody will be able to use it as it is, it woud be better to ask the owner to make the required changes in directory structure.
